# Macro for No Fill and No Borders

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for an excel Macro that will set all the cell fills to no fill and make all cells have no borders. I have multiple spreadsheets in my workbook and want this to apply to all of them. I've looked all through the internet looking for something that does this, but came up short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.  Just add it to any sub and you're good to go:

```
Dim wsCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer

wsCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 to wsCount
    Worksheets(i).Activate
    Cells.Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
Next i
```